# Search and copy files listed in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

Hi I'm working on a simple script that copy files from a directory to another based on a dataframe that contains a list of invoices.

Is there any way to do this as a partial match? like i want all the files that contains "F11000", "G13000" and go on continue this loop until no more data in DF.

I tried to figure it out by myself and I'm pretty sure changing the "X" on the copy function will do the trick, but can't see it.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import shutil

data = {'Invoice':['F11000','G13000','H14000']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Doc'])


path = 'D:/Pyfilesearch'
dest = 'D:/Dest'

def find(name,path):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root,name)


def copy():
    for x in df['Invoice']:
        shutil.copy(find(x,path),dest)



copy()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

- This is part of the standard library
- Treats paths and objects with methods instead of strings
- [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
- Script assumes `dest` is an existing directory.
- [`.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) searches subdirectories for files

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import shutil

# convert paths to pathlib objects
path = Path('D:/Pyfilesearch')
dest = Path('D:/Dest')

# find files and copy
for v in df.Invoice.unique():  # iterate through unique column values
    files = list(path.rglob(f'*{v}*'))  # create a list of files for a value
    files = [f for f in files if f.is_file()]  # if not using file extension, verify item is a file
    for f in files:  # iterate through and copy files
        print(f)
        shutil.copy(f, dest)
```

### Copy to subdirectories for each value

```py
path = Path('D:/Pyfilesearch')

for v in df.Invoice.unique():
    dest = Path('D:/Dest')
    files = list(path.rglob(f'*{v}*'))
    files = [f for f in files if f.is_file()]
    dest = dest / v  # create path with value
    if not dest.exists():  # check if directory exists
        dest.mkdir(parents=True)  # if not, create directory
    for f in files:
        shutil.copy(f, dest)
```